# Accessing Express server on EC2

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm using Express on my Amazon EC2 server. My server looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/my_view/true', function (req, res) {
      //do something
      res.render('view', {var1: somevalue});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I access my Express app locally using `http://localhost/view/true`, it works and I get my template displayed in browser.

But when I try use it on EC2 via `ec2-myinstance.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/view/true` I get `This site can’t be reached. refused to connect error`.

I've added HTTP 80 port in my AWS EC2 Security Group settings but it's still not working.
Can someone help?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works the same, but when I use Heroku, I need to do `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the server to listen at port 80, instead you are listening at port 3000. So either open up the port 3000 in the security group or listen at the port 80.

```js
app.listen(80);
```

The above change should work. Let me know if it works.